# how can i fix my timer?i don't know why it doesnt work

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to make a timer and i cant make it stop. im using setinterval() and clearinterval() im new using this methods so i dont know if im using them in the rigth way
heres my code:

```
var estado = "desactivado";

function play() {
  if (estado == "desactivado") {
    console.log(estado);
    estado = "activado";
    var mytimer = setInterval(() => {
      timer();
    }, 1000);
  } else if (estado == "activado") {
    clearInterval(mytimer);
  }
}
function timer() {
  let segundos = document.getElementById("segundos");
  let minutos = document.getElementById("minutos");
  let horas = document.getElementById("horas");
  if (segundos.value < 60) {
    segundos.value++;
  } else {
    if (segundos.value == 60) {
      if (minutos.value == 60) {
        horas.value++;
        minutos.value = 00;
        segundos.value = 00;
      } else {
        minutos.value++;
        segundos.value = 00;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the issue is with the scope of the variable `mytimer` - each time you call `play` it's a different variable, therefore `clearInterval(mytimer)` won't work

Comment: because myTimer is defined in the function.... FYI: setTimeout is not accurate for a timer.

Comment: please the HTLM part of ths... -> HTML element with id="segundos" is what ? a select box?

Answer (score 1):

You just defined the mytimer inside the if{} block. So you can't get the value in else block. Maybe you can define the var mytimer on the same level with estato.